# save output of command in array

Tags: xml, shell, freebsd

I'm using FreeBSD server, where is no bash, how can I save command in an array?
Ive got command, which works `grep '<description' amitOrServer.xml | cut -f2 -d">" | cut -f1 -d"<"`

Im trying to save variables in `<description />` from xml file.
XML file looks like this:

```
<amitOrServer>
 <item> 
  <title>AMIT</title>
  <description>DISABLE</description> 
 </item> 
 <item> 
  <title>GPS</title> 
  <description>DISABLE</description>  
 </item>  
</amitOrServer>
```

I need to save DISABLE parameters in the variable to work with them later in the shell script.

a script where I save parameters in variables.

```
 #!/bin/sh

    chosenOne=( $(grep '<description' amitOrServer.xml | cut -f2 -d">" | cut -f1 -d"<") )
    amit= "$chosenOne[$1]" #"ENABLE"
    gps= "$chosenOne[$2]" #"DISABLE"
```

I've got error like  Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
Can anybody help me, how can I save these parameters from XML file in the array?

Comment: check the details provided in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137566/arrays-in-unix-bourne-shell

Comment: You can also `pkg install bash`.

Comment: thank you Fidel for your answer. It really helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try to this:

```
#!/bin/sh

AMIT=$(grep AMIT -A1 items.xml | awk -F '[<>]' '/description/{print $3}')
GPS=$(grep GPS -A1 items.xml | awk -F '[<>]' '/description/{print $3}')

echo ${AMIT}
echo ${GPS}
```

In case you have python, this may also work:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xmldoc = minidom.parse('items.xml')
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('item')

out = {}
for i in itemlist:
    title = i.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
    description = i.getElementsByTagName('description')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
    out[title] = description

print out
print out["AMIT"]
print out["GPS"]
```